# c++ compile-time check function arguments

Tags: c++

I'm searching a way to check function arguments in compile-time if it's possible to do for compiler.

To be more specific:
assume that we have some class Matrix.

```
class Matrix
{
    int x_size;
    int y_size;

public:
    Matrix(int width, int height):
        x_size{width},
        y_size{height}
    {}
    Matrix():
        Matrix(0, 0)
    {}
};

int main()
{
    Matrix a; // good.
    Matrix b(1, 10); // good.
    Matrix c(0, 4); // bad, I want compilation error here.
}
```

So, can I check or differentiate behavior (function overloading?) in case of static (source-encoded) values passed to function?

If value isn't static:

```
std::cin >> size;
Matrix d(size, size);
```

we're only able to do runtime checks. But if values are encoded in source? Can I make compile-time check in this case?

EDIT: I think this can be possible with [constexpr constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr), but anyway overloading with and without constexpr isn't allowed. So problem can't be resolved in way I suppose.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to break the compilation if someone pass wrong arguments. Normal way is to throw exception on wrong values

Answer (score 6):

To get a compile time error you would need a template:

```
template <int width, int height>
class MatrixTemplate : public Matrix
{
    static_assert(0 < width, "Invalid Width");
    static_assert(0 < height, "Invalid Height");
    public:
    MatrixTemplate()
    : Matrix(width, height)
    {}
};
```

(Btw.: I suggest unsigned types for indices)

If you do not have static_assert (here I switch to unsigned):

```
template <unsigned width, unsigned height>
class MatrixTemplate : public Matrix
{
    public:
    MatrixTemplate()
    : Matrix(width, height)
    {}
};

template <> class MatrixTemplate<0, 0> {};
template <unsigned height> class MatrixTemplate<0, height> {};   
template <unsigned width> class MatrixTemplate<width, 0> {};
```

There is no support for empty matrices (MatrixTemplate<0, 0>), here. But it should be an easy task to adjust the static_asserts or class MatrixTemplate<0. 0>.

Comment: That's the puppy! I was just about to code this. Have an upvote. You can also do this with a `constexpr` but a certain compiler doesn't net support it ;-(

Comment: I think about this way, but I assume that matrix sizes aren't constant for Matrix object lifetime. So it works, but inapplicable in my case.

Comment: There is a typo in your code: `static_assert<` instead of `static_assert(`.

Comment: @AlexanderSergeev If you want the Matrix size to possibly change at runtime (why?), you will need runtime checking anyway.

Comment: @Lumen I'm not going to say I don't need runtime checks, but I want to have both of them.

Comment: @Lumen, and why: matrix class is needed to store images and convolution matrix applied to this image. In some cases I need to crop image or add frame to make processing of pixels located close to boundaries easier.

Comment: @DieterLücking BTW as you can see in question I needed not to restrict matrix sizes but to make sure that empty matrix have 0x0 size (not 0xn or nx0).

Answer (score 4):

You may add a method like this:

```
template <int WIDTH, int HEIGHT>
Matrix CreateMatrix()
{
    static_assert(WIDTH > 0, "WIDTH > 0 failed");
    static_assert(HEIGHT > 0, "HEIGHT > 0 failed");

    return Matrix(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}

int main() {
    Matrix m(0, 2);     // no static check
    Matrix m2 = CreateMatrix<0,2>(); // static check

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good idea. One could make the factory method `CreateMatrix` a static member function of `Matrix` and make the constructors private. Then every external construction is statically checked (if this is desired).

Answer (score 1):

The way that linear algebra packages tend to do this is to use templates for fixed size matrices, as in:

`template<int x, int y> class Matrix { ... }`

and an extra class for matrices that can change size at runtime

`class DynamicMatrix {...}`

You still have to rely on the programmer actually using the first option when they want fixed size matrices, but the template version makes it easy to generate a compiler error when `x` or `y` are zero.

Answer (score 0):

Run-time:

```
Matrix(int width, int height):
    x_size{width},
    y_size{height}
{
        assert(x_size>0);
        assert(y_size>0);
}
```

Compile-time (Actually you couldn't do it with function arguments. You can use template ways):

```
template <size_t WIDTH, size_t HEIGHT>
class Matrix
{
    const size_t x_size = WIDTH;
    const size_t y_size = HEIGHT;

    static_assert(WIDTH > 0, "Width must > 0");
    static_assert(HEIGHT > 0, "Height must > 0");
};
```