# Disable function only for compile-time argument

Tags: c++, type-traits

I want to disable a function for any compile-time evaluated argument (a literal, or something that comes from a constexpr expression). Is that possible?

For integers, it is possible to do the opposite use non-type template arguments, but that would also change the call syntax.

I am playing around with strict integers, that needs to be initiated somehow. Current rule for handling bad input:

- If the source value is only known at runtime, and a narrowing cast would destroy the interpretation (not the bits), an exception is thrown
- If the source value is known at compile time, and it wouldn't fit there should be a compilation error.

My idea was to disable the constructor that accepts a wider type for all constexpr arguments.

By strict, I mean that only value-preserving conversions are allowed:

Assume N >= M

- `int<M>` to `int<N>` Always OK
- `uint<M>` to `uint<N>` Always OK

For everything else:

1. There should be a compilation error if the source value is known at compile-time.
2. If the value is not known during compilation, see if a conversion would work properly, otherwise throw an exception.

For case (1), using the constexpr-throw trick does not work: Consider the following (non-constexpr context):

```
// Will compile, but it shouldn't. Instead of not compiling it will throw an exception.
int<16> foo(12345); 

// Will compile. Whatever the type of some_value_from_outside is, 
// check that it fits at runtime. If it does not, throw an exception.
int<16> thisIsFine(some_value_from_outside);
```

**What would be ideal is *overload resolution with respect to constexpr argument*, which does not exists, so I am trying to find the best workaround.**

Comment: I'm tempted to say there's another problem behind your apparent need

Comment: What is the real problem you're trying to solve. No, not the problem of "disable function only for compile-time argument", but the real problem for which you think the solution must be to "disable function only for compile-time argument".

Comment: Please define *strict integer*. I cannot guess what you mean; or explain (or at least give some example of) what is a non-strict integer.

Comment: Even the latest edit don't provide any [MCVE]. I don't understand what are `M` and `N` and where do they come from. And `int<16>` looks strange. Do you mean `int16_t` ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Sorry for bad markup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++ compile-time check function arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18981752/c-compile-time-check-function-arguments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accept that for now, there is now possibility to check that an expression is constexpr, neither through overloads (might be interesting to have), or any other approach. However, for reference I should list the current workarounds here:

1. Declare constants as constexpr and use the following idiom

   ```
   value fits in type ? cast to type : throw CastException
   ```

   This wil only compile if value fits in type, since otherwise the function is not constexpr.
2. Use an alternative templated factory method as mentioned [c++ compile-time check function arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18981752/c-compile-time-check-function-arguments).

I will go for (1), since it does not require different syntax for the constexpr case. Also, I think it is good practice to name constants anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to disable a function for any compile-time evaluated argument

It is not possible, and it makes no sense (in general).

In practice, with the [as-if rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule), most [optimizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) compilers will generate the *same* code for `f(2);` and  `{ int i=2; f(i); }` since both have the same [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)).

With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and also [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/), you might use [`__builtin_constant_p`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html)

With GCC, you might spend weeks or months coding your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) which would detect (and emit a diagnostic for) calls to function with compile time argument (e.g. you could implement your new [function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) in a plugin). But that won't change overloading or typing rules. And I really don't recommend making a plugin in your particular case.

Your question stays unclear, and it looks like you want something C++ does not provide. BTW `int<16>` is not legal C++ because `int` is not a template. Maybe you want [`std::int16_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) ?

Did you consider some other approach, perhaps generating C++ code from something else, maybe using some other preprocessor (e.g. [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp) or m4) or C++ code generator (your own one, perhaps; Qt [moc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/why-moc.html) or GNU [bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) or [SWIG](http://swig.org/) might be inspirational).

Comment: `__buildin_constant_p` does not solve the problem, as you cannot feed it into `static_assert`.

Comment: @BasilieStarynkevitch StackOverflow understand the question, and suggests a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18981752/c-compile-time-check-function-arguments?rq=1, which is basically what I need to do.